# Ng-click Scope inside link of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

Can you describe me, why I can't get value of local variable `directiveElement` inside `link` function of directive in `ng-click` method?

Here's code:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .directive("cell", ABCDirective);

function ABCDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><button ng-click="doSomething()">Change background</button></div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var directiveElement = element;

            scope.doSomething = function() {
                **** Uncaught ReferenceError: directiveElement is not defined(…) ****
            };
        }
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: You need to set your module like this: .module("app",[])

Comment: Also, what are you trying to get from the element?

Comment: This is part of my module - module is created somewhere else. Second thing - I want to let's say change background color of my button.

Comment: Well, element refers to "cell", not the button.

Comment: So, using jQuery, you could do something like this within your link function: $('button',directiveElement).css('background','red');

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular inside a directive sounds like a recipe for a disaster. Angular has it's own, light 'jQuery' version

Comment: actually, directives are where you want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that, to change background color:

```
 return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><button ng-style="{\'background-color\':myColor}" ng-click="doSomething()">Change background</button></div>',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.myColor = 'red';

                scope.doSomething = function() {
                     scope.myColor = 'blue';
                };
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend applying CSS rules within a directive if you can avoid it. Instead, I'd recommend setting an ng-class so that your stylesheet can alter the color appropriately.

That said, take a look at this example code sourced from the docs:

```
angular.module('dragModule', [])
.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {

return {
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

  element.css({
   position: 'relative',
   border: '1px solid red',
   backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
   cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    // Prevent default dragging of selected content
    event.preventDefault();
    startX = event.pageX - x;
    startY = event.pageY - y;
    $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
    $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
  });

  function mousemove(event) {
    y = event.pageY - startY;
    x = event.pageX - startX;
    element.css({
      top: y + 'px',
      left:  x + 'px'
    });
  }

  function mouseup() {
    $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
    $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
  }
}
};

}]);
```

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

As for the undefined variable, you shouldn't need to assign the function parameter to another variable in the first place. Can you post the code that actually triggers this error? (not just the error message in place of the code)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I find using `element.on('...', function() { ... });` confusing. I read this article on Angular's page and couldn't apply their recommendations to my purpose.